# Can I make my checks for Bilinear forms shorter?

Tags: linear-algebra

First I'll define what I talk about:

A **bilinear form** on a vector space V is a mapping:

$F: V \times V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, (a,b) \mapsto F(a,b)$

which is linear in every argument:

$a, b, c \in V$ and $\lambda, \mu \in \mathbb{R}$:

- $F(\lambda a + \mu b, c) = \lambda F(a, c) + \mu F(b, c)$
- $F(a, \lambda b + \mu c) = \lambda F(a, b) + \mu F(a, c)$

If I get an expression which could be a bilinear form, I check those two. This can be quite long.

A bilinear form F is **symmetric**, if:

$\forall a, b \in V: F(a, b) = F(b, a)$

Now my **question**:
If I know that a mapping is symmetric, can I make the checks for bilinearity shorter? Something like that:

$F(\lambda a + b, c) = \lambda F(a, c) + F(b, c)$?

If it is not possible, do you have counterexamples where it doesn't work?

Comment: No, that should be fine, and you can prove it: take $F(a, \lambda b + c)$, use symmetry, expand everything out using linearity in the first argument, and flip the arguments of all the resulting terms.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I missed something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a proof that it works:

**Pre.:**

$f:V \times V \to \mathbb{R}, (a,b) \mapsto f(a,b)$

(I) Symmetry: $f(a,b) = f(b,a)$

(II) Short biliniearity: $f(\lambda a + b,c) = f( \lambda a, c) + f(b,c) = \lambda f(a, c) + f(b,c)$

**statement**: f is a bilinear form

**proof**:

**part 1**: 
$f(\lambda a + \mu b, c) = \lambda f(a, c) + \mu f(b, c)$

$f(\lambda a + \mu b, c) = (II) f(\lambda a, c) + f(\mu b, c) = \lambda f(a,c) + \mu f(b,c)$

**part 2**:
$f(a, \lambda b + \mu c) = \lambda f(a, b) + \mu f(a, c)$

$f(a, \lambda b + \mu c) = (I) f(\lambda b + \mu c, a) = (II) f(\lambda b, a) + f(\mu c, a) = \lambda f(b, a) + \mu f(c, a) = (I) $
$= \lambda f(a,b) + \mu f(a, c) \blacksquare$